# How to map values from List<String> into a List<Model>

Tags: arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I'm practicing Java 8 features and I got to a problem that I couldn't solve:

I have a *List of Strings* that I need to map into a *List of Customers*, the *List of Strings* only has the name of the customers, but *Customer Model* has other properties:

```
 public class Customer {
    private int id{get; set;};
    private String name{get; set;};
    private String company{get; set;};
}

public static List<Customer> convertList() { 

    List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    
    List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    nameList.add("Customer A");
    nameList.add("Customer B");
    nameList.add("Customer C");
    nameList.add("Customer D");
    nameList.add("Customer E");
    nameList.add("Customer F");
    
    return customerList.stream()
                       .map()//here I got stuck
                       .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
}
```

What I want to do is to to set the value of the List into the Name property of the List, I tried using a stream and map but couldn't figure how to use it in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
List<Customer> customerList = nameList.stream().map(name -> {
     Customer c = new Customer();
     c.setName(name);
     c.setId(generateId());
     c.setCompany(getCompany(name));
     return c;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You need to map the `nameList` to `customerList` so, you should stream on the `nameList` and convert it to `customerList` not the other way around.
Next, you need to figure out how to get the additional information like id, company etc using some external method/service if at all that is required during the `map()` operation.